# ASP.NET: How to check the value of a cached dictionary?

Tags: asp.net

Not really sure how to do this but i can cache the dictionary like this:

Cache.Insert("CacheName", Dictionary)

need some direction. the dictionary is two string values taken from a database.  The user will input a string and i need to compare it against the values in the cached dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you need to access the object from the cache, cast it, and the use the ContainsKey property. Here is an example:

First add the dictionary to the Cache:

```
IDictionary<string, string> testDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
testDict.Add("Test", "test");
Cache.Insert("dict", testDict);
```

Then, when you need to do so, access the cached object and use it ContainsKey property to determine whether it contains the searched key or not.

```
 var dict = Cache["dict"] as IDictionary<string, string>;

 if (dict != null)
 {
     string testValue = "test";
     if(dict.ContainsKey(testValue))
     {
        /* some logic here */ 
     }     
 }
```

You can access the value the following way:

```
if (dict != null)
 {
     string testValue = "test";
     if(dict.ContainsKey(testValue))
     {
        /* some logic here */ 
        string value = dict[testValue];
     }     
 }
```

Comment: That seems to work pretty swell, now i just need to get the key of the value which was found and set it equal to a string

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dictionary out of the cache by writing

```
var dict = (Dictionary<X, Y>) cache["CacheName"];
```